# Dell Vostro 3560 Webcam Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, webcam

I have a Dell Vostro 3560 notebook and its webcam is not recognized by ubuntu 12.04

My lsusb output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:648b Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It's definitely recognized: `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:648b Microdia`, why did you think it wasn't?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have a vostro 3560 and am having problems with installing the video card ati, the last driver from amd site does not install, how did you do with yours? I can pass as did the installation?